# Why is my program not working like it is supposed to? random number generator from 1 to 10

Tags: python

i tried making a game that generates 3 random numbers 1 to 10 but its not working

import random

```
def numberRandom(:
   random_number = random.randint(1,10)
   return random_number

print(numberRandom
```

i think its supposed to work

Comment: 1) It won’t even parse correctly due to a blatant syntax error; 2) remember to *call* a function using parentheses: `print(numberRandom())`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. _Specifically_, what does "not working" mean?

Answer (score 1):

There are some pretty blatant syntax errors.
On the first line the ':' is in the wrong place. And the print command does not have closing brackets nor does it have any brackets calling the function. This will come with experience in python, so keep trying.

To correct your code I would instead do this:
(of course you would need to import 'random' at the top of the code)

```
def numberRandom():
    random_number = random.randint(1, 10)
    return random_number

print(numberRandom())
```